# How to keep Outlook UI responsive in C# VSTO addin when making lots of CPU-intensive work on UI thread

Tags: c#, outlook, async-await, vsto

I have the code which makes many calls to Outlook API in a loop. Outlook doesn't like access to its API from worker threads so I have to use main thread for that. The part of the code which makes network queries is perfectly fine with async/await so the UI does not freeze. But when the code reaches CPU-intensive part (calls to Outlook API), UI obviously freezes.

I inserted `await Task.Delay(1)` which executes after each 10ms elapses but since timer resolution is not so precise (15ms), it makes the code noticeably slower (although unblocks UI).

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
int interval = 10;
foreach (SomeItem item in items)
{
    // Intense access to Outlook API...
    // ...

    DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now;
    if (d2.Subtract(d1).TotalMilliseconds > interval)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        d1 = d2;
    }
}
```

Using `Task.Yield` instead of `Task.Delay(1)` does not unblock UI (MSDN anyway doesn't recommend Task.Yield for this).

Increasing `interval` from 10ms to larger values (100ms) reduces performance loss to the minimum and makes UI somewhat responsive but not so smooth.

Maybe there is a better alternative which wouldn't imply any tradeoffs between UI smoothness and performance? Maybe like a good old `Application.DoEvents` but in a modern and recommended way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to do that using OOM alone. Extended MAPI is thread safe, but it is only accessible from C++ or Delphi. You can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (any language - I am its author) - its [RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) family of objects is purely MAPI based and can be used from a secondary thread. Save `Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT` into a dedicated variable on the main thread (this way only that variable would have to be marshalled). On the secondary thread, create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object (this way the MAPI system will be initialized on that thread) and set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to the variable saved on the main thread. This way the two will share the same MAPI session. You can then retrieve the folder using `RDOSession.GetFolderFromID`/`GetDefaultFolder`/etc. and process the items.

Comment: Yeah, I know that not using OOM at all would eliminate the issue but it's not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know OOM can't be used from secondary threads, or you may get an exception in the code. The latest versions of Outlook
detect such use cases and may throw an exception. But you are free to use a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or any other wrapper around that API such as Redemption.

Note, in case if you deal only with Exchange profiles you may consider using EWS or Outlook API for getting the required data on secondary threads. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the possibility of using EMAPI or EWS. But my question was much more "narrow" and specific. It was about processing UI events in the main thread, not about alternatives to OOM (that would be a different and very big story).

Comment: There is no trivial mechanisms for implementing the desired functionality. I believe users will trap into delays and UI freezes in that case anyway. Why do you reject Extended MAPI? That's is exactly the case when it should be used by Outlook developers.

Comment: In theory, yes. But in practice, it's gonna be too much work to rewrite the whole app to use Ext. MAPI. I just don't have enough resources for that.